# archive/tar: invalid tar header when executing pack builder create

Tags: docker, pack, buildpack, paketo

The issue only occurs on my Mac, a colleague could create the builder without issues on his Linux machine.

This is the command line:

```bash
$ pack builder create builder-jammy-base:first --config ./builder.toml -v
```

And this is the relevant part of the output:

```bash
Creating builder with the following buildpacks:
-> paketo-buildpacks/java@10.6.0
-> paketo-buildpacks/apache-tomcat@7.14.2
-> paketo-buildpacks/apache-tomee@1.8.0
-> paketo-buildpacks/azure-application-insights@5.17.3
-> paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica@10.4.4
-> paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates@3.6.7
-> paketo-buildpacks/clojure-tools@2.8.14
-> paketo-buildpacks/datadog@4.8.0
-> paketo-buildpacks/dist-zip@5.6.8
-> paketo-buildpacks/encrypt-at-rest@4.5.13
-> paketo-buildpacks/environment-variables@4.5.6
-> paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar@6.8.3
-> paketo-buildpacks/google-stackdriver@8.0.4
-> paketo-buildpacks/gradle@7.7.1
-> paketo-buildpacks/image-labels@4.5.5
-> paketo-buildpacks/jattach@1.4.9
-> paketo-buildpacks/java-memory-assistant@1.4.9
-> paketo-buildpacks/leiningen@4.6.9
-> paketo-buildpacks/liberty@3.8.12
-> paketo-buildpacks/maven@6.15.12
-> paketo-buildpacks/node-engine@3.1.0
-> paketo-buildpacks/procfile@5.6.8
-> paketo-buildpacks/sbt@6.12.11
-> paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot@5.27.8
-> paketo-buildpacks/syft@1.42.0
-> paketo-buildpacks/watchexec@2.8.7
-> paketo-buildpacks/yarn@1.2.0
ERROR: creating paketo-buildpacks/java@10.6.0 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-0: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/apache-tomcat@7.14.2 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-1: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/apache-tomee@1.8.0 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-2: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/azure-application-insights@5.17.3 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-3: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica@10.4.4 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-4: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates@3.6.7 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-5: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/clojure-tools@2.8.14 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-6: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/datadog@4.8.0 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-7: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/dist-zip@5.6.8 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-8: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/encrypt-at-rest@4.5.13 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-9: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/environment-variables@4.5.6 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-10: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar@6.8.3 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-11: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/google-stackdriver@8.0.4 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-12: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/gradle@7.7.1 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-13: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/image-labels@4.5.5 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-14: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/jattach@1.4.9 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-15: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/java-memory-assistant@1.4.9 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-16: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/leiningen@4.6.9 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-17: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/liberty@3.8.12 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-18: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/maven@6.15.12 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-19: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/node-engine@3.1.0 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-20: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/procfile@5.6.8 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-21: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/sbt@6.12.11 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-22: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot@5.27.8 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-23: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/syft@1.42.0 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-24: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/watchexec@2.8.7 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-25: archive/tar: invalid tar header
creating paketo-buildpacks/yarn@1.2.0 tar file at path /Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/buildpack-26: archive/tar: invalid tar header
```

The path `/Volumes/ramdisk/` is `$TMPDIR` and writable, other processes write to it normally. Even a directory `/Volumes/ramdisk/imgutil.local.image.2064056153` will be created in the process.

Comment: Do you see it create `/Volumes/ramdisk/create-builder-scratch3415883560/` (or similar) and does it leave any files in there? It should fetch the buildpacks and put them there. It might be failing to fetch them or possibly fetching something that's corrupted. If it leaves the files there, you could see what it's fetching. Or maybe try a `ctrl+z' to suspend the process, then look at the tmp directory it's created and see what's in there.

Comment: @DanielMikusa No, only the before mentioned folder will be created and left empty.

Comment: If that happens almost immediately, then it's probably an issue trying to fetch the buildpacks. That would explain why the folder is empty. It's not able to fetch and create anything. Idk why it wouldn't be able to fetch them though. Check your network & proxy settings. Aside from that, I'm not sure.